# Does AWS Cognito supports Nested User Pools?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am trying to find information/comments if aws cognito supports nested user pools. Think LDAP group of groups. Is this possible? Can anyone share your experience or point me to the right reads?

Appreciate it.

Comment: User pools are separate by design. Perhaps you mean cognito user groups?